# Pachner moves for graph of 4-valent nodes

Tags: graph-theory, triangulation, simplex

For 3-simplices (i.e. tetrahedra), I understand the basic idea behind the Pachner moves 1 $\leftrightarrow$ 4, which takes one tetrahedron and replaces it with four (or vice versa), and 2 $\leftrightarrow$ 3, which shifts between 2 and 3 tetrahedra. These moves can also be defined on the dual graph to the tetrahedron, where the graph has a 4-valent node corresponding to each 3-simplex, and each edge in the graph corresponds to a face of the tetrahedron.

However, I am curious specifically about performing this 2 $\leftrightarrow$ 3 move on an arbitrary 4-valent graph. Is there an ambiguity about which edges you put together at each of the new nodes, when you go in the 2 $\to$ 3 direction? Since you seem to lack information about whether a triangulation is dual to the graph, it appears to me you have six possible choices of how to join the edges up. Going the other direction, 3 $\to$ 2, also seems to have an ambiguity in how to group edges into two groups of three.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the ambiguity that you mention does exist. This is because the dual graphs do not completely represent a triangulation. Each triangulation has one dual graph; but each such dual graph can be created from many triangulations.

Self plug: If you want to see a modification of the dual graph representation that does not lose any information of this information, feel free to read through http://arxiv.org/abs/1412.2169. In this setting you can perform the $2 \leftrightarrow 3$ and $1 \leftrightarrow 4$ Pachner moves without any ambiguity.